# how to sync /home directory in Linux (centos)

Tags: centos, rsync, synchronization, unison

How can I keep in sync my `/home` directory on two different systems?

I found something like unison, but it is no longer in the repositories of centos9.
Are there other possible solutions?

The synchronization should take place in both directions and it must be possible to work with multi users on both systems.

Comment: People say good things about [syncthing](https://syncthing.net). I do like unison though — you could [build unison from source](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison).

Comment: product suggestions are offtopic, but you might want to use nfs to do so

Comment: rsync using PKI infrastructure will be a safe/secure option.
Set up SSL keys and add each host to the other's authorisedkeys, and then set up a script on a cronjob, or use inotify to trigger the sync on changes

Comment: trent, i belive he wants a 2 way instant sync, moreover there is a [similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/195571/cross-syncing-home-directories-with-disconnected-operation-linux-ubuntu?rq=1) question

Comment: thanks, I would prefer basic tools like rsync. Sync speed is not the main issue. The main problem is deleting while changes can be made on both systems at the same time. In the worst case, data can be incorrectly deleted with rsync.

Comment: +1 for Syncthing.  On Devuan/Debian, I have it syncing my full Desktop directory on 6 separate systems: 2 laptops, 3 desktops and one headless server running a daily cron job for a month's worth of Desktop backups.  Some of those connections are to a distant location across the Internet with custom firewall holes.  Works great, it's almost real-time, and I've NEVER lost a file.  Just remember: The last file updated is the one you'll get.  As a 'savior' option, Syncthing allows you to save the deleted file in a '.stversions' directory with configurable parameters.  See: https://syncthing.net/

Answer (score 0):

I personally syncing is not a good idea when having two systems accessing the data.
I could imagine a scenario where data is being changes by users and in the same time also edited by users on node2, that would definitely create data corruption.
And also imagine a user charging a file the sync comes and overwrites the changes.

In this matter, providing a collaboration environment like SharePoint Online would be better. Then a file gets locked for editing when a user is working on it.

Comment: I care about the home directories of users. In this case, a user would have to edit a file on both systems.